# Azure service bus dead letter

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to resubmit all the deadletter messages back to its original queue.  When I resubmit the message,  it's again moving to deadletter.
This time I thought there might be some problem with the message.  When I debugged it,  it was having no problem. 
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Specifically, how are you moving it back from the deadletter to the original queue?

Comment: What's the dead-lettered reason on the messages moved into DLQ? It's a good starting point for your investigation. Debugger might skew things.

Comment: It says maximum delivery count reached!  @Sean

Answer (score 2):

Possible scenarios your messages end up in the DLQ are:

1. Too slow processing, message `LockDuration` expires and message is retried again until all of the `DeliveryCounts` are exhausted and message is DLQ-ed.
2. You have an aggressive `PrefetchCount`. Messages that are prefetched and not processed within `LockDuration` time are subject to `DeliveryCount` increase (see #1)
3. Too short of `LockDuration` causing messages to being processed while the re-appear on the queue and picked up by other processing instances (or if you use OnMessage API with concurrency> 1).
4. Processing constantly failing, causing message eventually to end up in a DLQ.

I suspect you have #4. Not sure how you re-submit, but you have to clone the message and send it back. There was a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798643/resubmitting-a-message-from-dead-letter-queue-azure-service-bus/41798700), have a look.

Comment: BrokeredMessage sendMsgBackToQueue = new BrokeredMessage();

sendMsgBackToQueue = msg.Clone();

client.Send(sendMsgBackToQueue);

                            msg.Complete();

Comment: Code looks fine. Can you post a link to a simple  repro code?