# in azure logic app submit the message from dead letter queue to topic

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

IN Azure Service bus topic  how the messages are moved from dead letter queue to topic?

whether it will automatically moved to topic or  we need to configure the properties of topic  in portal or whether there is any other way to do it?(i prefer not to use any code here i wish to do only configuration changes)

Comment: do you mean from a subscription to the dead letter subscription ? I don't really understand what you are trying to do ? could you please explain a little bit more ? Do you want to resubmit the message ?

Comment: i want to resubmit the messages from dead letter queue to topic.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no automatic magic to do this. You can increase the MessageDeliveryCount but after a while it make sense not to retry messages that always fail

Comment: you probably are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798643/resubmitting-a-message-from-dead-letter-queue-azure-service-bus

  have a look

Answer (score 0):

We had a batch of around 60k messages, which need to be reprocessed from the dead letter queue. Peeking and send the messages back via Service Bus Explorer took around 6 minutes per 1k messages from my machine. I solved the issue by setting a forward rule for DLQ messages to another queue and from there auto forward it to the original queue. This solution took around 30 seconds for all 60k messages. This works well for queues and topics.