# Resubmitting messages from deadletter on Azure service bus on Topic queue with partitioning and duplicate detection enabled

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, dead-letter, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am trying to resubmit messages from the deadletter queue on a Azure service bus that is configured with a topic queue that has partitioning and duplicate detection enabled.

When I try to add one or more messages I get this error

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.PartstatusResubmitFunction. Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus: Message to a partitioned entity with duplicate detection enabled must have either PartitionKey or MessageId set TrackingId:3dd6017e-c7ea-408e-b167-b5c78cfef8ed_G19,

I tried to give messageId and PartitionKey a new value on but it keeps giving me this error.

I set the MessageId and PartitionKey like this

```
ServiceBusMessage resubmitMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(dlqMessage);
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 1000);
resubmitMessage.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
resubmitMessage.PartitionKey = randomNumber.ToString();
```

This is done from an Azure function, where I use ServiceBusOutput to resubmit the message

```
[Function(nameof(PartstatusResubmitFunction))]
[ServiceBusOutput("partstatus", EntityType = 
ServiceBusEntityType.Topic, Connection = "connectionString")]
public async Task<List<ServiceBusMessage>> 
RunAsync([TimerTrigger("%CronTab%")] TimerInfo myTimer) 
{
if (myTimer.ScheduleStatus is not null)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: 
{myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
}

var props = await administrationClient.GetSubscriptionRuntimePropertiesAsync("partstatus", 
subscriberName.Replace("/$DeadLetterQueue", ""));
activeMessageCount = props.Value.ActiveMessageCount;
List<ServiceBusMessage> result = new List<ServiceBusMessage>();

if (activeMessageCount < 10000)
{
    var deadletterCount = await 
ProcessDeadLetterMessagesAsync($"topic: partstatus -> subscriber: 
{subscriberName}", 10, result);

    while (deadletterCount > 0)
    {
        deadletterCount = await 
ProcessDeadLetterMessagesAsync($"topic: partstatus -> subscriber: 
{subscriberName}", 10, result);
    }
}
else
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Not resubmitting messages from 
deadletter, ActiveMessageCount: " + activeMessageCount);
}

return result;
```

}

Thanks

Comment: How did you try to assign the MessageId or PartitionKey?   It would be helpful to show a code example of what you're attempting to do.

Comment: @andersmi, Are you trying to implement this with Azure function?

Comment: Yes I am using an Azure function.

Answer (score 0):

I could resubmit and process the messages from the dead-letter topic of the Azure service bus using below code Azure function.

- Thanks for the code [Fanetic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68632602/19991670).

**Code Snippet:**

```cs
    var connectionString = "<Service_Bus_connection_string>";
    var topicName = "<Topic_Name>";
    var subscriberName = "<subscription_name>";
    var fetchCount = 10;
    var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
    var sender = client.CreateSender(topicName);
    var dlqReceiver = client.CreateReceiver(topicName, subscriberName, new ServiceBusReceiverOptions
        {
            SubQueue = SubQueue.DeadLetter,
            ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock
        });

    var wait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

    log.LogInformation($"fetching messages ({wait.TotalSeconds} seconds retrieval timeout)");
    log.LogInformation($"topic: {topicName} -> subscriber: {subscriberName}");

    IReadOnlyList<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> dlqMessages = await dlqReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(fetchCount, wait);

    log.LogInformation($"dl-count: {dlqMessages.Count}");

        int i = 1;
        foreach (var dlqMessage in dlqMessages)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"start processing message {i}");
            log.LogInformation($"dl-message-dead-letter-message-id: {dlqMessage.MessageId}");
            log.LogInformation($"dl-message-dead-letter-reason: {dlqMessage.DeadLetterReason}");
            log.LogInformation($"dl-message-dead-letter-error-description: {dlqMessage.DeadLetterErrorDescription}");

            ServiceBusMessage resubmittableMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(dlqMessage);

            await sender.SendMessageAsync(resubmittableMessage);

            await dlqReceiver.CompleteMessageAsync(dlqMessage);
            log.LogInformation(dlqMessage.ToString());
            log.LogInformation($"finished processing message {i}: "+dlqMessage.Body.ToString());
            log.LogInformation("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            i++;
        }

         await dlqReceiver.CloseAsync();
        log.LogInformation($"finished");
```

**Console output:**

[image]

**Processing multiple Dead-letter messages:**

```cs
Functions:

        Function1: serviceBusTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-03-27T09:32:11.187Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-03-27T09:32:21.404Z] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=6fe5f19c-06ff-42a1-ab4b-1d9ac4c06efa)
[2024-03-27T09:32:21.410Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 30df9f87837f4aedb61ef4e262056801, SequenceNumber: 13, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2024-03-27T09:32:20.5520000+00:00, LockedUntilUtc: 2024-03-27T09:33:20.5520000+00:00, SessionId: (null)
[2024-03-27T09:32:21.467Z] C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {MessageId:30df9f87837f4aedb61ef4e262056801}
[2024-03-27T09:32:21.477Z] topic: topic1 -> subscriber: mysubscription
[2024-03-27T09:32:25.834Z] dl-count: 2
[2024-03-27T09:32:25.837Z] start processing message 1
[2024-03-27T09:32:25.842Z] dl-message-id: 6373663f877e4431b9e57f29903b4492
[2024-03-27T09:32:25.844Z] dl-messagereason: TTLExpiredException
[2024-03-27T09:32:25.846Z] dl-message-description: The message expired and was dead lettered.
[2024-03-27T09:32:28.037Z] finished processing message 1: Hello Pravu
[2024-03-27T09:32:28.040Z] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2024-03-27T09:32:28.043Z] start processing message 2
[2024-03-27T09:32:28.046Z] dl-message-id: e9187857a5c442dbb9d20ed4bc37f50d
[2024-03-27T09:32:28.049Z] dl-messagereason: TTLExpiredException
[2024-03-27T09:32:28.052Z] dl-message-description: The message expired and was dead lettered.
[2024-03-27T09:32:28.727Z] finished processing message 2: Hello
[2024-03-27T09:32:28.731Z] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2024-03-27T09:32:29.109Z] finished
[2024-03-27T09:32:29.189Z] Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=6fe5f19c-06ff-42a1-ab4b-1d9ac4c06efa, Duration=7929ms)
```

Comment: I tried to test this and it works on my queue with Partition and duplicate message activated. Can't understand why this works even without setting a new MessageId and partitionID? 
If possible, I would rather do it with the ServiceBusOutput because it is cleaner and Azure function itself handles resubmitting the messages.

Comment: So, do you want the code to implement the same with ServiceBusOutput or are you able to achieve it by your above provided code?

Comment: If I can't get it to work with ServiceBusOutput, I will have to use the above code, but I would prefer using ServiceBusOutput. I don't understand why the above code can resubmit the messages without changing the MessageID and PartitionKey.

Comment: The above code doesn't add all messages, I resubmitted 113 messages and only 81 was submitted, no errors was thrown. I have no consumer running.